# how to find value of attribute of a node following another node?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am searching for an xPath for following XML file having content

```
<library>
    <book id="12013"> 
         <title>ABCD</title>
    </book>


    <book id="23422"> 
        <title>Efgh</title>
    </book>
</library>
```

here i need to find value of the attribute "id" of node book next to book node having id "12013". i should get answer as "23422".

what i have used is something like this

```
//library/book[@id='12013']/following::book/@id
```

but it is not returning any value.

Comment: seems to be correct xpath, what are you getting in return?

Comment: if i give xpath as  //library/book[@id='12013']/following::book/title then it gives me "Efgh".. but i want attribute value not node value.

Comment: can you show me how you're trying to get the value?

Comment: it's working fine, tested it here-http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Comment: ohh yeah.. it is working properly there let me check it again. I am using this xpath in a java application. passing xpath and xml file to that function and it returns the value. let me try it again.

Comment: got it. there's no problem in xPATH . i was expecting a single value bt when i used nodelist i got the answer. btw thanks Sunny for ur help.